# Problem with giving id to action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I configured routes in Global.asax.cs like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Post", "Post/Show/{PostId}", new { controller = "Post", action = "Show" });
```

and this is preview of used controller with action:

```
public partial class PostController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Show(int PostId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that it selects Show() action to use but it gives no int value,therefor it gives null.Here is an example of URL I used:../Post/Show/0

**EDIT:**
When I configure my routes like this :

```
        routes.MapRoute("Post", "Post/Show/{id}", new { controller = "Post", action = "Show" });
        routes.MapRoute("Timeline", "{controller}/{action}/{Page}", new { controller = "Timeline", action = "List" });
```

everything works fine,but when I configure it like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute("Timeline", "{controller}/{action}/{Page}", new { controller = "Timeline", action = "List" });
        routes.MapRoute("Post", "Post/Show/{id}", new { controller = "Post", action = "Show" });
```

2nd route "Post" fails.
Why ?!

Comment: The order should always be specific to general. `Post/Show/1232123` will always match the exact same pattern as `{controller}/{action}/{page}`. You could always put route constraints on the route itself to weed out unwanted routes from matching but there's no reason why (based on your above routes) you would even need to swap them.

Comment: Based on your timeline route. That route will basically act as your default route. Is that what you want? Any request to `http://site.com/` will match your Timeline route.

Comment: No, I don't want that , I have set defoult route:
routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });

Comment: Just making sure. If you want you could post your whole route setup and I can take a look at it to see how it will route. Or! You can download/install Glimpse ( http://getglimpse.com ) to see what matches what and why.

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
routes.MapRoute("Post", "Post/Show/{PostId}", new { controller = "Post", action = "Show", PostId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: As Bobby said, the order is important, the route I suggusted MUST be before the default route. You could also use the default route instead of a custom, you could replace all the PostId by id and it should map directly to the default mvc route

Comment: above this route I have another route which works as it should ( just like route in question should,with id). This is that route: routes.MapRoute("Timeline", "{controller}/{action}/{Page}", new { controller = "Timeline", action = "List" });

Comment: I would try to move it after the other one.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just remember the order the routes appear in global.asax is very important too.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Post", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Post", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
            )
```